# 404 for all the site collections

Tags: 404

I am getting 404 error on site collections. I did a backup from one farm and restore it 2nd farm. On second farm I am getting 404 errors. Please suggest.

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: can you explain how you did your backup?

Comment: SharePoint backup from CA. and same way restore.

Comment: And there is no log being generated. the main site comes up IIS7 default page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seeing the IIS default page it means that SharePoint is not listening on the hostheader:port that you are requesting.  Verify that the host header and port are correct both in IIS and in Central Administration-Alternate Access Mappings.  Also, remember that restoring a site collection does not create the corresponding web application so you would have to do that manually before the site collection is visible.  Also, a web application can only have one root site collection so you may need to move databases around in order to see the restored content.

Comment: Dave: You are right. The host header created in AAM did not add binding values in IIS. I added them manually and wala now sites are resolving. Why wouldn't CA take care of the binding when I added AAM.

Comment: It is supposed to but I've also had the same thing happen in the past.  Not sure why but it happens it is frequent enough to make it a common place to look for web app weirdness.

Comment: From other answers I'v seen, I think *Wise* is a good name for David.